# Connecting VPN by Mac OS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, vpn, firewall

I'm trying to install Firebase in to my Xcode by using mac os terminal command `pod install` (CocoaPods) , but it always has overtime, and connection breaks, so i cannot install it.

So here is a problem, i live in China, and i can't connect any Google services via terminal(GitHub also), but i have full access to all services using my VPN App.

Few solutions that i found - to create a custon VPN connection by command `networksetup -connectpppoeservice "myVPN"` but it doesnt work too, because i'm using VPN desktop App, and have no idea what data i need to type inside. Also i tried to `networksetup -setv6off "Wi-Fi"`, but it didn't help too. I read people said that solution was just to turn off VPN, but in my case i have the same result with VPN ON/OFF.

So i have a question - how can i manage traffic from terminal through my VPN app to reach servers?
My MacOS version: 10.15.7 Catalina

[errorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyZe8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found how to solve my problem:

i opened a socket port from my VPN distributor

`git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:****`